# LDA as a dimensionality reducer

Tags: r, feature-selection, lda

I know how to use LDA as a classifier.
But how to use **Linear Discriminant Analysis** as a **dimensionality reducer** to reduce the number of features and **apply logistic regression on top of it**.
I am using R language.

Comment: Please provide more context about the problem .  btw the wording makes it sound like a homework assignment: in particular the somewhat "random" toss-in of "applying logistic regression" without explaining why that were chosen

Comment: Please consider editing your question. In its' current form it is at risk of being closed.

Comment: I am trying to apply feature selection and go with logistic regression,instead of going blindly with random forest. My independent features being continuous and dependent categorical variable I am going with Linear Discriminant Analysis for feature selection, prior to applying logistic regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do LDA via the lda function from the MASS package. The reduced dimension data can be computed as follows:

```
# Model Discriminant Analysis
library( MASS )
model = lda( class ~ ., data = X_train )
# Ploting LDA Model
projected_data = as.matrix( X_train[, 1:18] ) %*% model$scaling
```

You can then feed the projected_data into another supervised learning method.

Credit: The code is obtained from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/is-lda-a-dimensionality-reduction-technique-or-a-classifier-algorithm-eeed4de9953a).